# I often wonder (to whom does a nation owe / to whom a nation owes) its greatest debt of gratitude

Tags: exam-questions

> I often wonder to whom does a nation owes its greatest debt of gratitude.

This sentence is from an error correction exercise. I see two possible grammatical ways to correct the sentence either by removing *does* or changing *owes* to *owe*. Since it's not an interrogative sentence I am more inclined to former one, Which one is the correct way ?

Comment: Probably, you should change **it's** to **its** too.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious error here is "does owes" -- there should be only one nonfinite verb; that is, "to whom does a nation owe."

Unfortunately, there is another problem that may be just a pet peeve of my own.  If I owe someone a dollar, then I give him a dollar, and he's happy.  If I owe someone a debt, then I give him a debt, and he shouldn't be happy about it.

So I would rewrite the sentence: "I often wonder who the nation should have the most gratitude for."  (Or, to be formally correct but not colloquial:  "I often wonder for whom the nation should have the most gratitude."

Comment: to whom a nation owes, there is no question: to whom does a nation owe x?